# Word - Is there a list of all field commands?

Tags: microsoft-word

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> in Word, then a gray field which looks like this appears: `{  }`. This field accepts different methods, e.g. `PAGE`, which returns the current Page Number.

**NOTE**: You have to right click on it and enable fieldfunctions to call this function.

However, I only know the method `PAGE`, is there a list of all available commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on a field and click Edit Field to bring up the Field dialog box.

This dialog shows all available Field Codes along with options for each.

Note: You can also insert a field by clicking on Insert (ribbon), Quick Parts, Field.